# Complex Static Library Linking

Tags: xcode, linker, static-libraries

So I have nested Static Libraries several times in the past but never quite like this and its causing a bit of an issue.

For now lets assume I have 3 static libraries, A, B, and C. And one project that uses them as follows.

A is a base library composed of commonly used Custom Views, Data structures, and Categories. B is a library linked with A that contains view controllers shared among several projects. C is another library linked with A that contains view controllers shared among several projects.

This particular project uses code from B and C. So the structure looks like this:

```
   A
  / \
 B   C
  \ /
Project
```

And since the way Xcode links static libraries basically merges them, B and C both have all of A's symbols. So I'm getting the duplicate symbols linker error. How do I go about dealing with this? Do I need to weak link something? Or is there a particular flag I'm missing? Do I need to set up some type of dependency other thank linking binaries?

I've googled and search here and found lots of good information but nothing I've been able to twist into this particular situation.

**Update on Thoughts**

So let me ask this as it seems to be a possible solution after reading that Static Libraries while capable of being merged really shouldn't be.

Rather than having 3 independent Static Libraries should I put them all in one project and merely have multiple static library targets? Not even using Target Dependencies, just A, AB, and AC, and ABC targets that include the proper files and headers for their target? This will no doubt be rather complicated for build settings and could make source distribution a bit complex, but it would solve my current problem and possible be the better way to handle things. Whatcha think?

Comment: Why would `B` and `C` contain `A`'s symbols?  That doesn't sound right at all.

Comment: Because they are linked libraries.

Comment: But if `B` is a static library and `A` is static library, then `Project` must link with both `A` **and** `B`.  In other words `B` does not contain `A` until the final link with the binary.

Comment: But B is built on top of A. So atleast in the way Xcode handles it, A is contained within B. If I don't link A with B, then B won't compile as its missing necessary code used from A.

Comment: That's wrong then.  A static libary (`.a` file) is simply an archive of `.o` files.  You need to break `A` from `B` and `C` so make them separate Xcode projects and use a Workspace to bring them together.  `B` and `C` will have to see `A`'s header files but it won't link any of `A`'s objects files.  `Project` will need to see `{A,B,C}`'s header files and `.a` files in order to link correctly.  Once you've done this your duplicate symbols will disappear.

Comment: To further clarify (hopefully) when you build a static library you **don't** link with dependencies; this is only done when you link the final binary (or dynamic library).

Comment: So I've read some stuff like this before. But it seems inherently wrong to include the headers from A in B/C just so the compiler doesn't get mad. Is this really the proper way? Or is it a work around for my current problem? Basically what I'm saying is this a sign I shouldn't be coupling static libraries?

Comment: No; this is correct and cannot work any other way (`B` needs to know the interface to `A`'s classes in order to compile correctly).

Comment: Alright. Thanks for your help. Throw it in an answer and I'll mark it correct. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are not creating static libraries `B` and `C` correctly as you are including  object files from static library `A`.  This is incorrect.  Instead make `A`, `B` and `C` contain only their own classes's object files and bring them all together in the final link of the `Project` binary.

- You will have to allow `B` to see `A`'s header files in order to compile correctly.
- You will have to allow `C` to see `A`'s header files in order to compile correctly.
- You will have to allow `Project` to see `A`'s, `B`'s and `C`'s header files in order to compile correctly as well as `A`'s, `B`'s and `C`'s library (`.a`) files in order to link correctly.

I *think* that an Xcode Workspace will take care of all of the header/library search path settings for you, once you set-up the project dependencies correctly, but I could be wrong about that and you might have to set those paths up yourself.

Comment: Thanks. Xcode's Workspaces will definitely handle this pretty well.